# Is Firebase Messaging Service (for notifications) sticky?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using now Firebase for notifications for my app and I know that many users just clean their RAM sometimes so it can kill my service. I know that on Android's default service there's a method called `onStartCommand` which returns something, like `return START_STICKY` so the service will start again once it's killed. Does the Firebase service do that by default or I need to implement a method in order to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically don't need to worry about the implementation details of Firebase SDK internal components.  They should work as documented.  If you're observing behavior that doesn't match the documented behavior, that's a bug, and we'd encourage you to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for those.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question being asked ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Firebase messaging service does not start in START_STICKY mode. If you follow the classes that FirebaseMessagingSerivce extends, you will figure that out. I am myself in need to start FirebaseMessagingService in sticky mode to handle custom notifications, however still trying to figure out how.